# Property access must assign to the property or use its value Error - Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is my code:

```
If testarray(0) = "ProgRun]webbrowser]color=red]url=" Then
            fullweb.Show()
            fullweb.WebBrowser1.Navigate(testarray(1))
            fullweb.Button1.BackColor.Coral()
        End If
```

I get error: Property access must assign to the property or use its value 
HELP!

Comment: `Button1.BackColor` is a property that needs to be _**assigned a value**_, which is pretty basic programming knowledge. Have a look at how the assignment operator works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator

Comment: Or, as the error message states, use its value.  Dim myColor as Color = fullweb.Button1.BackColor

Answer (score 0):

This line will throw an exception (at design time) by the compiler:

```
fullweb.Button1.BackColor.Coral()
```

the reason is that there is **no** such method `Coral()`

if you want to change the back color of the button you need **set / assign** `BackColor` property:

```
fullweb.Button1.BackColor = Color.Coral
```